# Burninate [pxe] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There was an effort to close all off-topic questions tagged with [pxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pxe) (not started by me).
Now there are 53 questions, and they are all [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpxe%5D%20closed%3Ano).
I suggest to burninate this tag.

Using criterias from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):
**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
No

> This is kinda self-explanatory; Stack Overflow doesn't need a kittens
>   tag, at least not until someone releases a hot new framework and names
>   it "Kittens". All that a blatantly off-topic tag is gonna do is
>   encourage blatantly off-topic questions, so removing it is good for
>   everyone. Just be sure and do your homework: the last thing you want
>   is to start removing tags only to be attacked by a bunch of angry
>   kitten.js users.

Comment: BTW, kitten.js is a thing: https://github.com/ben-ng/kitten-js

Comment: Wait, wait, wait, what? How is PXE not on-topic for this site? Okay, I'll give you that most of the questions that have that tag are almost certainly off-topic, but that doesn't mean the tag itself is.

Comment: @CodyGray I thought that it is more related to hardware, and not related to programming

Comment: Well, hardware has to be programmed. Someone has to write the software that controls PXE, and there are PXE boot scripts written by programmers.

Comment: Then tag wiki should be updated, it should say that questions related to programming PXE-related stuff are tagged with it, not just questions about using it.

Comment: I strongly believe that is noise. On a programming Q&A site, we do not need to go around writing in tag wikis that the tag is meant to be used on programming questions. It is implied.

Comment: `All that a blatantly off-topic tag is gonna do is encourage blatantly off-topic questions` permaban [tag:seo] and [tag:kali-linux] pls

Comment: @Will then you can support my request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag is gone. Somebody just deleted or retagged all remaining questions (not me).